# SSIS : Works fine from BIDS but returns different data from SQL agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an issue with an **SQL agent JOb**, when it runs local and from **SSIS** Package, it completes with no execution errors. But when run local from BIDS there's a column in my table that receives the right info (numeric (28,5)), except that when run from the SQL agent there's a Null value that is affected to this column.

Is there a particular reason leading to this behavior?

Is there a special setting that I need to add?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I do run package on 32 bit

Comment: It's unclear what problem you are specifically encountering. Are you saying that when you run the package with dtexec and sqlagent, the data is loaded correctly, but not when you run it with BIDS? Are you sure your connection settings are the same at runtime for all environments?

Comment: actually it's the oposite, when I run it with BIDS the data is fine, but when I run it from a job from sql server then I have Null instead of my data

Comment: Are you deploying the latest file from the SSIS package using the sql agent. If it is the latest then there should not be any difference in execution of the package with both, Check your TFS for the check in ...

Comment: When i run into weird things like this, I find it's useful to dump results into a flat file along various steps of the way, to see where the problem lies. But I suspect that your problem may be more along the lines of @developer 's comment

Comment: I import it from my computer to make sure that I have the same version but still the same behavior

Comment: how does the SQL Server Agent Job access the Package, through File System, SSIS Catalog or anything else?

Comment: Any chance the SQL Agent user has different permissions to the data? When you run from BIDS, it uses your account. when you execute the package from SQL Management Studio, it uses your account. When a job on SQL Agent runs the package, it uses the SQL Agent account.

Comment: @BhupeshC : I first connect to the integration services server, then i import the ssis through file system, then i create a job that runs the SSIS

Comment: @Bill, I only have this issue with one column, the other ones are fine and I'm able to get the correct info

Comment: the data type of this column is numeric(28,5), does it have anything to do with this behaviour?

Comment: do you have any other column with the same datatype? and whats your package source in the SQL Server Job?

Comment: @BhupeshC : I have another numeric(19,5) and it works fine, so I assume that the type has nothing to do with it

Comment: What type of source is it? Text? Excel?

Comment: Source from a CSV file. I do this (ISNULL(TOTAL_QTY) ? "0" : REPLACE(TOTAL_QTY,".",",")). Then I convert to numeric[DT_NUMERIC] before writing to the DB.

Comment: Have you tried dumping your output to a flat file before and after your conversion, to see if it's the conversion that's causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your time.

The problem was identified. Both computer and server are on the same region, but the regional settings on the computers were modified to set decimals to '.' and not ',' while they remained the same on the server.

Sorry for the trouble. I just hope that this answer will help other people that are facing the same problem.

Comment: All this make me think of onother question : Is there way to determin where's the SSIS launched from? I need to be able run it from my computer for tests and on the server for PROD (I can't modify the existing settings for my computer and the server)